# Import existing MySQL db into MySQL db in Azure

Tags: mysql, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have created and publish a new Website on MS Azure, I have also created a MySQL db along with the site (using the same wizard). However I'm not sure how to access or query this db, I would like to import a sql schema into this db, but I'm not sure how to do so. 
Basically I would like to import the table definitions my website is using into the new MySQL db created by Azure using the new Website wizard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL databases on Windows Azure are provided by ClearDB, a 3rd-party.

On the [management portal](https://manage.windowsazure.com/#Workspaces/StoreExtension/Store), click on **Add-ons**, select your database, then click on **Manage your add-on**.

[image]

From there, you'll be redirected to the ClearDB website. Your connection information will be under the **Endpoint Information** tab.

[image]